# Why aren't my radiators heating up after I replaced a rusted through pipe?

Tags: central-heating

We had a bit of corrosion in an old pipe and it started leaking and losing pressure and so I drained all the central heating system (radiators), replaced the pipe and fitting. It was awkward and the new pipe had to go through from the first floor to the ground floor.

I then filled up the radiators again until the pressure was between 1-2 bars and switched the heating on again. The boiler (INTERGAS KOMPAKT HR?) is currently sitting at 85 but none of the pipes or radiators are hot. I can't hear any water moving around in them like I used to. We still have hot water.

I've bled all the radiators until nothing but water came out. There were a couple that let out a lot of air. The pressure in the system went right down to 0.3 bar and so I topped up the system with water until it was 1.25 bar again.

Panel on heating system currently saying desired temperature has been reached and all the radiators are stone cold. Room temperature 14 °C and desired temperature is 20 °C.

I bled all the radiators again: no air came out. I repressurised the system to 1.8 bar.

I have no idea what to do now. Any advice?

Comment: Sure sounds like a bit of rust flaked off and is blocking somewhere.  Intake to circulation pump seems like a likely spot to look.  Seems the unit is Dutch.  https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.intergas-verwarming.nl%2Flijsten%2Ffiles%2FBediening%2520Kompakt%2520Solo%2520HR%2520880.647-04.pdf

Comment: Can you check the pump is getting power and is in fact running? Do you have a room thermostat?

Comment: SOLVED. I waited 24 hours for the gunk to settle, tapped out some of the pipes gently with a small hammer and switched it on. Took about 3 hours to warm the house up from bone cold. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

According to OP in comment above:

> I waited 24 hours for the gunk to settle, tapped out some of the pipes gently with a small hammer and switched it on. Took about 3 hours to warm the house up from bone cold.

(Answered to remove this Q from list of Qs with no answers.)